# How to write SQL to fetch the data of a column in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables tblA & tblB. Now I want to fetch the name by op_code.

```
tblA
op_code    |     date    |    num
------------------------------------------------
 a         |      03/01  |    34
 b         |      04/03  |    5556
 c         |      03/05  |    555

tblB
id    |     op_code    |    Name
------------------------------------------------
 1    |       a        |    Jet
 2    |       b,c      |    Mike
 3    |       d        |    Tom
```

As the op_code data in tblB is a combination data, so I try to write sql as below.

```
   select a.*, b.* 
     from tblA a 
LEFT JOIN tblB b on a.op_code in (SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.op_code, ',', 13))
```

It doesn't work. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Note: If you can, normalize the data and don’t use columns that have multiple values like this. If you can’t then the answers given provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET()` here:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tblA a
LEFT JOIN tblB b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(a.op_code, b.op_code) > 0;
```

But, as storing CSV data in your SQL tables is viewed as bad practice, because it is unnormalized data, you should only view this a temporary workaround query.  A much better plan would be to commit to having just one record for each `op_code` relationship in the B table.

Just for fun, here is another way to write your query using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tblA a
LEFT JOIN tblB b
    ON b.op_code REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', a.op_code, '[[:>:]]');
```

[image]

Here is a demo for the second version of the query:

### Demo

Comment: thx a lot, Tim and Nick ~. just a question, why cannot use IN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.op_code, ',', 13))? does it mean SUBSTRING_INDEX will not get the result ( 'a', 'b' ) ?

Comment: @kuehne `SUBSTRING_INDEX` _could_ be used to separate `b,c` into separate values, but in general it can't handle a CSV string of arbitrary length.  You need `FIND_IN_SET` or `REGEXP` for that.